# Mock async_task of Django-q

Tags: django, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, django-q

I'm using [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/) and I'm currently working on adding tests using `mock` for my existing tasks. I could easily create tests for each task without depending on django-q but one of my task is calling another `async_task`. Here's an example:

```py
import requests
from django_q.tasks import async_task

task_a():
    response = requests.get(url)
    # process response here

    if condition:
        async_task('task_b')

task_b():
    response = requests.get(another_url)
```

And here's how I test them:

```py
import requests

from .tasks import task_a
from .mock_responses import task_a_response

@mock.patch.object(requests, "get")
@mock.patch("django_q.tasks.async_task")
def test_async_task(self, mock_async_task, mock_task_a):
    mock_task_a.return_value.status_code = 200
    mock_task_a.return_value.json.return_value = task_a_response

    mock_async_task.return_value = "12345"

    # execute the task
    task_a()

    self.assertTrue(mock_task_a.called)
    self.assertTrue(mock_async_task.called)
```

I know for a fact that `async_task` returns the task ID, hence the line, `mock_async_task.return_value = "12345"`. However, after running the test, `mock_async_task` returns `False` and the task is being added into the queue (I could see a bunch of `01:42:59 [Q] INFO Enqueued 1` from the server) which is what I'm trying to avoid. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to mock not @mock.patch("django_q.tasks.async_task") but @mock.patch("your_filename.async_task")

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the task from being added to the queue, you need to change the configuration `sync` to True when the tests are running. You can find more info about the configurations [here](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configure.html#sync)